# Como tomo una determinada cantidad de opciones en c|#

Tags: c#

necesito ayuda en proyecto del instituto... el proyecto consiste en  elaborar un programa que ayude a un puesto de comida.... el problema que no puedo solucionar es el siguiente.

"Tipo de Pan, carne y hasta un máximo de 4 ingredientes adicionales (tal como lechuga, tomates, bacon, pepinillo, etc) que el cliente pueda seleccionar para agregar a su hamburguesa. Cada uno de estos ingredientes llevan un cargo adicional en el precio, por tanto, usted necesita algún modo de contabilizar que tantos ingredientes se han agregado y calcular el precio (para la hamburguesa base y todos los ingredientes adicionales). Esta hamburguesa tiene un precio base y los adicionales llevan un precio adicional por separado. "

en esta parte no encuentro la forma de que el cliente tome una cantidad aleatoria de ingredientes es decir una forma en la que si el cliente selecciona solo dos ingredientes se guarden solo esos. he intentado crear metodos con parametros pero como resultado necesito ingresar exactamete 4 ingredientes en fin quisiera encontrar una forma en la que solo se guarden la cantidad de ingredientes que el cliente desea.(el problema es en c sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que planteas se resuelve aplicando el `Patron Decorator`

[Patrón de Diseño Decorator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1-3BrkvCT4)

Si bien en el video se explica en java, aplica igual en c#, peor vi que alli se explicaba muy claro como implementarlo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[The Decorator Pattern | Set 2 (Introduction and Design)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/the-decorator-pattern-set-2-introduction-and-design/)

Al ir aplicando capas puedes obtener el costo al componerlas mediente el patron obteniendo el costo total sin importar la cantidad de adicionales que se selecionen

Hay mucho material para investigar del patron, pero si quieres una recomendacion, consigue el libro

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]